# HOw to convert it into generic form

Tags: java, generics

I have written below function which I want to write it as generic for all java bean which will return me list of type the bean name being passed.

```
public List<_ItemCreditQuality> getCrediQuality(String type,String def) throws SQLException{

        sql = "";

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
        ResultSetHandler<List<_ItemCreditQuality>> h = new BeanListHandler<_ItemCreditQuality>(_ItemCreditQuality.class);
        creditQualityList = run.query(con, sql, h);

        return creditQualityList;
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: Can't see much good coming of this code `sql = "";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
`

Comment: don't go on what is written over there. sql will be added later on.

Comment: Sorry, the phrase _"return me list of type the bean name being passed"_ does not make sense.

Comment: okay @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1):

Make a few assumptions, here is an example:

```
public <T> List<T> getCreditQuality(Class<T> beanClass) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + beanClass.getSimpleName();
    try (
        Statement stmt = this.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    ) {
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
        ResultSetHandler<List<T>> h = new BeanListHandler<T>(beanClass);
        List<T> creditQualityList = run.query(this.con, sql, h);
        return creditQualityList;
    }
}
```

`T` could then be the `_ItemCreditQuality` bean class, and you'd call it like this:

```
List<_ItemCreditQuality> list = getCreditQuality(_ItemCreditQuality.class);
```